# Cannot install package: dlx

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm new to anaconda.

How can I install the dlx package (https://pypi.org/project/dlx/) in anaconda?

I found it here: (https://anaconda.org/auto/dlx).

`conda install auto::dlx`

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - auto::dlx
  - secretstorage
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I get no result from `conda info auto::dlx`.

Can anyone help me?

### SOLUTION:

Thanks to vivekwisdom for leading me on the right path.

PyCharm created a virtual environment. I had to activate it first (`source activate <name_of_venv>`) and then install dlx using pip. It didn't work via `conda install auto::dlx` because it was missing cython, which I also installed via pip.

Comment: Try pip install dlx

Comment: @krayyem: DLX is then still not available from within conda.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [link](https://anaconda.org/auto/dlx) you provided, `conda install -c auto dlx` is the correct way to install the package in Anaconda.

Comment: This doesn't work. `conda install -c auto dlx` is equivalent to `conda install auto::dlx`.

Comment: You Can open conda terminal and run `pip install dlx`, to open prompt In the Search box type Anaconda , Choose Anaconda Prompt from the list